# Entity name conflicts in Visual Studio

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to the Entity Framework.  I've created a model-first schema in Visual Studio 2012 with EF5, but I'm having trouble getting the generated code to build.  One of my entities ("Test") has the same name as the model (`edmx`) and the project (`csproj`) files, so it conflicts with the namespace (Test is a `namespace` but is used like a `type`).  So I decided to change the namespace by setting a "Custom Tool Namespace" for the .tt files.  This worked, but then I found that the "Test" entity's generated .cs file was entirely empty (other entities were generating properly), so I had build errors where other entities reference "Test".  Renaming the entity results in a properly generated class, and therefore a building project, but I really want to use the original name.

I will probably end up scratching the project and starting over, ensuring to choose unique names for the project, the model, and the entity.  But I'd rather know how to fix this if possible in case I run into something similar when the project is further along and it's not so easy to start over.

Answer (score 0):

you can use use an alias on the Using Directive, e.g. `using Project = PC.MyCompany.Project;` to differentiate between namespaces.  see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)